# How to get all connected nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

[image]

I want to get list of all connected nodes starting from node 0 as shown in the diagram

Comment: Can you be a little more precise ? what is result do you want to have ?

Comment: I want to get a list of all the connected nodes. For example in the above case when I search for connected nodes for 0, it should return nodes- 1,2,3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I want to get a list of all the connected nodes. For example in the
>   above case when I search for connected nodes for 0, it should return
>   nodes- 1,2,3

This query will do what you want:

```
MATCH ({id : 0})-[*]-(connected)
RETURN connected
```

The above query will return all nodes connected with a node with `id=0` (I'm considering that the numbers inside the nodes are values of an id property) in any depth, both directions and considering any relationship type. Take a look in the section [Relationships in depth](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#relationships-in-depth) of the docs.

While this will work fine for small graphs note that this is a very expensive operation. It will go through the entire graph **starting** from the start point `({id : 0})` considering any relationship type. This is really not a good idea for production environments.

Comment: in case of cyclic graph , it is giving duplicate nodes

Comment: @chetandev Try: `MATCH (root {id : 0})-[*]-(connected)
WHERE root <> connected
RETURN distinct connected`

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to match the nodes that have a relationship to another node, you can use this:

```
MATCH (n) MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN n,r
```

It will return you all the nodes that have a relationship to another node or nodes, irrespective of the direction of the relationship.

If you wish to add a constraint you can do it this way:

```
MATCH (n:Label {id:"id"}) MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN n,r
```

Comment: Can I do something to get a deep nodes
i.e not just ones directly connected to n

Comment: MATCH (n:Label {id:"id"})
MATCH(q:Deep_Node {id:"id"})
MATCH (n)-[r]-(q) RETURN n,r,q

Answer (score 7):

For larger or more heavily interconnected graphs, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) offers a more efficient means of traversal that returns all nodes in a subgraph.

As others have already mentioned, it's best to use labels on your nodes, and add either an index or a unique constraint on the label+property for fast lookup of your starting node.

Using a label of "Label", and a parameter of `idParam`, a query to get nodes of the subgraph with APOC would be:

```
MATCH (n:Label {id:$idParam})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {minLevel:1}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Nodes will be distinct, and the starting node will not be returned with the rest.

EDIT

There's currently a restriction preventing usage of `minLevel` in `subgraphNodes()`, you can use either filter out the starting node yourself, or use `apoc.path.expandConfig()` using `uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL'` to get the same effect.